# make(generate) a vcd file using python or c or cpp

Tags: python, c++, c, wave, vcd

Question: Create a vcd file that shows a square wave with a constant frequency.

Any link you provide will be useful, because I searched a lot but I did not find anything and unfortunately I have no background.

We arent allow to code in verilog or system verilog.
We should code in python or cpp or c, and create a vcd file , then open it in a wave program to show square wave with a constant frequency.

editor which opens vcd file:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> With VHDL, you can use Modalism to generate a VCD dump file. (All the
> commands in bold are to be typed into the command window).

> To create a .vcd file:

> 1. Compile and load design successfully in transcript window

> 2. Specify VCD filename
>
> - Syntax: **vcd file** <file_name>.vcd
>
> 3. Enable VCD to dump signals under a desired instance
>
> - Syntax: **vcd add** <path_to_instance>/*

Note: This command does not dump signals of children instances

Enable VCD for encrypted instances will generate warnings

> 4. Run simulation generate VCD database

> 5. Quit simulation

- Syntax: **quit sim**

If you have Xilinx ISE, you can use the following method to generate a VCD file. (These commands can by typed in at the command prompt in the lower half of the Xilinx ISE window).

```
vcd dumpfile results.vcd
vcd dumpvars -m /
vcd dumpon
run 1000 ns
vcd dumpoff
vcd dumpflush
```